# Profile And .env file

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I actually need help on TWO things!

My first one is a .env file to keep my "top secret" token in, but it just throws "Error: An invalid token was provided.".

Here is my code:

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const PREFIX = "> ";
```

and this is my .env file:

```
TOKEN=MYTOKENISHEREBUTIWANNABEPRIVATE
```

I do not understand why it can not read it?

And also I have this:

I want to make a little profile thingy, and this is my code:

```
    case "profile":
let userToGrabProfile = message.mentions.members.first();

var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
   .addField(userToGrabProfile, "Roles: " + userToGrabProfile.roles.map(role => role.name).join(", ")) // user, roles
   .addField("Stats", "XP: 0/100 Level 0") // XP, Level?
   .setColor(0x00ffff)
   .setThumbnail(userToGrabProfile.avatarURL)
message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
break;
```

}

but it does nothing. Nothing prints, i've tried adding a watch, nothing happens!

Comment: Try : TOKEN='MYTOKENISHEREBUTIWANNABEPRIVATE' (single quote added)

Comment: did you install dotenv ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Neither worked!

Answer (score 1):

Edited, (got more info from the comment)

Make sure you have `dotenv` installed.
And from your code, it doesnt look like you have

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Check the docs here: [npm/dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

## Otherwise:

#### If the above failed, try these:

in your .env file make sure you have your "variable" **properly** defined.
[image: Token]

Make sure you don't have any spaces or semicolons.

Make sure you're calling your token **after** you have required the .env file properly:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var token = process.env.token;
```

Comment: You have totally missed the point. I can USE the token, I just want to put it into a .env file, and call to it from there.

Comment: Thats more like it :P Got it now

Comment: Glad you got it working :D
If this answer helped would you mind accepting it?